# Efficient way to sample from matrix of probabilities n times with binomial distribution

Tags: numpy, random

I have a 2-dim matrix of probabilities.  I want to sample using a binomial distribution from this matrix n times.  What is the most elegant way to do this using numpy / scipy?

```
import numpy as np

test_mat = np.random.beta(10, 2, size=(10,3))
trials = 5

# this works but only 1 trial
np.random.binomial(1, test_mat)

# this gives error
np.random.binomial(1, test_mat, size = (10, 3, trials))
```

`ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`

Or is my only option to first reshape the test_mat array to be 3 dimensional (in essence slotting in the same values for all 5 columns in the 3rd dimension from a given row and column in the 1st and 2nd dims).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply do:

```
np.random.binomial(1, test_mat, np.r_[trials, test_mat.shape])
```

In the end you can reshape it the way you want

Comment: `size=(10,*test_mat.shape)` or `size=(10,)+test_mat.shape` also works.

Comment: What is `np.r_`?  `TypeError: 'RClass' object is not callable`

Comment: @matsuo_basho seems you tried to call `np.r_` Its not a function. Note that I used `np.r_[]` and not `np.r_()` it is used to concatenate various arrays rowwise

Comment: @Onyambu can you add a comment about why numpy requires the samples to be the first dimension - that is essentially what tripped me up, since I was trying to specify it as the 3rd dimension.  Perhaps it's spelled out somewhere in np documentation.

Comment: @matsuo_basho it's nothing about numpy. It's just the notion of arrays. You need n_trial arrays each 10*3. The n_trials become the first dimension

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I guess I don't understand why it errors out when I specify the 3rd dimension to be last, since for me it's easier to conceptualize that the first 2 dimensions are the 2 dimensions we're used to (i.e. time and variables) and then we add the dimensions for samples at the end.

Comment: @matsuo_basho but thats not how python works. the first dimension is often the dimension of observations. eg if I have 10000 images, each image is 28*28*3, then the array is not `28*28*3*1000` but rather `1000*28*28*3`. This is the same across almost all platforms.

Comment: Is that actually a Python rule, a matrix algebra rule or a numpy rule?  If it's a matrix algebra rule, fair enough, but if not, my point is that something that is obvious to someone who already knows it isn't to someone who's learning and it's not clear where that is described in the docs.

Comment: @matsuo_basho i do not believe its algebra. Although Its the same structure in python, c++ and matlab. Note that its just a common practice in machine learning. Its just easy to extract/index an image using the first index. ie `images[0]` directly gives you the first image. However, one can represent the data in any format they want as long as they maintain that data as such. Note that this will be difficult as most libraries/packages use the first index to represent an observation. Also note that it is not documented anywhere, just learned it through examples.